# Same reference/pointer for equal value in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would it be possible to return `a is b` as `False`? Looks like index 0 and 1 are pointing to the same value reference.

```
>>> arr = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> a, b, c, d = arr
>>> a is b
True
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: Short simple strings are interned by the Python interpreter you're using. That's why they're the same object.

Comment: You can't rely on `is` here. Is too bad